# How to get the values of multiple Check box field

Tags: checkbox, sencha-touch-2

I am new to Senchatouch and am struggling to get a value of Check box field. i know to get the value of single Check box field but i need to get the values of the selected Check box field and moreover I need to pass the value to the json data. Any help would be much appreciated. thanks in advance.

here is my code follows:

```
 {
xtype:'panel',
id:'panel1',
items:[
        {
            xtype:'panel',
            id:'pan1',
            hidden:true,
            layout:'vbox',
            items:[
                 {
                   xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                   id:'day1',
                    value: 'day1',
                    label: 'day1',
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                     labelWidth: '90%',
                listeners:{
                    check:function()
                                {
                                var a=Ext.getCmp('day1').getValue();
                                localStorage.setItem("day1" ,a);

                                },

                            },
                         },               
                                 {
                                  xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                                  id:'day2',
                                  value: 'day2',
                                  label: 'day2',
                                  labelAlign: 'right',
                                  labelWidth: '90%',         
                                    },
                                 {
                                    xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                                    value: 'day3',
                                    id:'day3',
                                    label: 'day3',
                                    labelAlign: 'right',
                                    labelWidth: '90%',
                                 },

                                                   ]
                                    },      
                                    ]
                             },
                                                        },
```

Answer (score 1):

`Ext.ComponentQuery.query("checkboxfield{isChecked()}");` should return all checkbox fields.

I think you should know what to do then.

Update: if you don't want to process each single checkbox field, it's easy to do it programmatically, like this:

```
for (var i=1;i<=3;i++){
    (function(index){
        var id = 'day' + index.toString();
        var component = Ext.getCmp(id);
        localStorage.setItem(id, component.getValue());
    }(i);
}
```

getting values from localstorage programmatically is similar.

Comment: I tried but am getting a error like Maximum call stack size exceeded. I don't need to get all the checkbox values. i need to pass only the selected checkbox values to the json data.

Comment: I have also used a listener function to store the selected check box values to the local storage. I need to pass the selected values alone to the json data.

Comment: I tried am getting the same error that maximum call stack size exceeded. Is there is any other way to get the values that i have stored in the local storage ? so that i can get the checked values from the local store and can pass to the json data??

Comment: loading from or saving to the local storage? Because the above command just looks for checked checkbox fields and then you will probably use to save to the local storage, similar to what you wrote `localStorage.setItem("day1" ,a);`. So eventually what do you mean?

Comment: its just a variable name that i have given to get the value of the first check box feild in the localstorage